# Read JSON Data With String Key: Angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to iterate json data in angular2.
If JSON Data is like this

```
{fileName: "XYZ"}
```

I am able to iterate using- **let data of datas**

But If my JSON data key is in string format, how I can iterate in angular2?

```
{"fileName": "XYZ"}
```

Comment: isn't it same as normal json data?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar, first one is iterating successfully using **let data of datas** but second one is not iterating using same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON **always** have double quoted string keys, so these:

```
{ fileName: "XYZ" }
{ 'fileName': "XYZ" }
```

Are not valid jsons, but this is:

```
{ "fileName": "XYZ" }
```

Javascript objects don't require the keys to be quoted, and if they are then a single quote can be used:

```
let a = { fileName: "XYZ" };
let b = { 'fileName': "XYZ" };
let c = { "fileName": "XYZ" };
```

Here `a`, `b` and `c` are equivalent.

In any case, iterating all of those js object is done in the same way:

```
for (let key in a) {
    console.log(`${ key }: ${ a[key] }`);
}

Object.keys(b).forEach(key => console.log(`${ key }: ${ b[key] }`));
```